# Is there a way to programmatically change the keyboard layout in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the layout from qwerty to qwertz/azerty etc.

Android has different InputMethodSubtypes under the Latin IME, which has varying layouts for different languages. What I'm trying to do is to allow the user to switch keyboard layouts based on their preference.

Comment: Definitely there is , you can find some apps in google play with the same functionality . I duuno the way how to get through it ,thats why i'm commenting and not answering . But yea I can assure you ,that its possible .

Comment: I'm actually not looking for the apps. I'm trying to set them programmatically.

Comment: Yea I understand that , thats why I mentioned  I dunno which way to get through it and hence i'm commenting and not answering, but surely thers way to do it

Comment: Keyboard layouts are under the control of the actual keyboard implementations; I'm not sure there's even a safe way to design an API like this (which isn't to say that it doesn't exist in a corner somewhere).

Comment: It looks as if Android doesn't provide an official way for apps to do that. There is a method `InputMethodManager.setCurrentInputMethodSubtype()` to change the subtype (which includes the layout), but calling this method requires `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission and works only if the app and the input method share the same UID (which is only an option if they are both from the same developer). Bottom line: Android apparently isn't designed to allow this, thus the only way to accomplish what you want (if at all) will be undocumented/unofficial, is not supported and may break in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is being a long time since this post, but I was recently trying to achieve the same, changing keyboard locales, so this might prove useful to someone.

In short, if the app does not have system level permissions it is not possible. It is recommended to display a settings dialog, like bellow:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

If your app however has system level permissions (unlikely) you can do the following:

Add the following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>`

Try the following code:

```
    String id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD
    );

    List<InputMethodInfo> enabledInputMethodList = inputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
    for (InputMethodInfo inputMethodInfo : enabledInputMethodList) {
        if (inputMethodInfo.getId().equals(id)) {
            List<InputMethodSubtype> enabledInputMethodSubtypeList = inputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(inputMethodInfo, true);
            for (InputMethodSubtype subtype : enabledInputMethodSubtypeList) {
                if (subtype.getLocale().equals(locale)) {                                   
                    Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.SELECTED_INPUT_METHOD_SUBTYPE, subtype.hashCode());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course the above method is hacky and will only work on if your app has system level privileges. I tried it on an device flashed with AOSP image and an app signed with Android OS platform keys.